# Show authors based on a two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to display a list of top authors and created a seperated array for it.

```
$top_authors = array(3) { 
        [0] => array(2) { 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["sale"]=> int(20)
        } 

        [1] => array(2) { 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["sale"]=> int(5) 
         }

         [2] => array(2) { 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "12" 
            ["sale"]=> int(125) 
         }  
     }
```

What's the best approach to create another array with user ID's only based on the most sales, so it becomes (`user ids: 12, 1, 3`)?

Then I can use it like this:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'theme_hook_top_authors_query', 
        array(
            'number'    => 10,
            'include'   => implode(',', $author_ids),
            'orderby'   => 'include'                                
        ) 
    );          

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Comment: What is the problem of using `for`, `foreach` or `array_map`?

Comment: How is the data of your best author storage? In XML? SQL? It's being created from a HTML form? This helps to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array_multisort to sort one array on base of other

```
$ids = array_column($top_authors, 'id');
echo array_multisort(array_column($top_authors, 'sale'), SORT_DESC, $ids);

print_r($ids);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: glad to help. Good luck!